# Where does the "Share on Facebook" meta information come from

Tags: facebook, metadata, share

I am building a new site with a FB share button. The share button exists on the home page (http://bit.ly/1J5uJyQ) as the first button icon in the share bar.

When you click the "f" share button and connect to the Facebook share page, where does the met info in the red box in my image come from?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bytqhoir_Tt5Z2t3M3lSTzlSbzg

Note this is the home page of a site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researched and found it --

Follow and use these links to solve the problem:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
- http://ogp.me/

Then the real key (ie., "trick") is to click the `Fetch new scrape information` button after loading the URL.